# how to use a C# nullable datetime in F#

Tags: f#

I have a C# method that returns a DateTime?

and I would like to do the equivalent of:

```
DateTime? D;
if (D == null)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    Date = (DateTime)D;
    ...
}
```

but in F#

how can this be done?

---

I tried this:

```
    match (d: Nullable<DateTime>) with
    | None -> printfn "null"
    | NonNull s -> printfn "d %s" s.ToString
```

but it doesn't work; the "None" doesn't compile

Comment: Can you change the method to return `Option` or do you have to work with `Nullable`?

Comment: I have a C# function that returns a DateTime? (from a DB call) and I'm expecting to do some logic in F# and then return a date or a null at the end. I've been doing F# for 30 min, so the answer may be very obvious :)

Comment: There is `Option.ofNullable` since F# 4, which you can use as an "adapter".

Comment: do you have a link showing how this works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First convert your value to `Option` via `Option.ofNullable`, then match on the result of that:

```
let nd = csharpMethod()
match Option.ofNullable nd with
| Some d -> printfn "Date = %A" d
| None -> printfn "Null date"
```

Answer (score 7):

Fyodor's approach with converting `Nullable` to `Option` is safer as you then have to use pattern matching to access the value, but it should be noted that you can also use the methods of `Nullable` directly:

```
let nd = csharpMethod()
if nd.HasValue then printfn "Date = %A" nd.Value
else printfn "Null date"
```

This might be better in a tight loop where you want to avoid extra allocation.